# ClickOnce Deployment Identity

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a new ClickOnce deploy I am trying to get setup.  While trying to install, I get this error:

> The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity

I have read that this means that there is a mismatch between the current version and the new version.

But I don't have a current version that I can see.  I checked "Add Remove Programs" and my app is not in there.

I also renamed the 'AppData\Local\Apps' folder so that it would not be able to see previous installs (just in case).

**Is there some other reason that I could be getting this error?  Or some other way to remove a previous version of a ClickOnce App?**